# A new field is added to the table that is not allowed to be empty, and then it is changed to be allowed to be empty, resulting in a query error

Tags: mysql

```
  MYSQL [user]> alter table user add age int(1) not null;
  MYSQL [user]> alter table user modify age int(1) null;
  MYSQL [user]> select * from user limit 1;
```

**database having data！**

> ERROR 1104 (42000): The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: Did you try doing `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1` like it suggested?

Comment: result is Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)，but database has data.

Comment: There are about millions of data in the database

Comment: Setting the variable doesn't affect any rows, it just allows future queries to work without error.